How to achieve SELECT FOR UPDATE in Mongo given this query?
Let's say I have a Collection called 'user_history'. It includes an array called 'history'. There is also a 'auto_increment' field in the Collection to simulate MySQL's one. There's a field called 'sequence' in each element in an array 'history' which is set current 'auto_increment' every time it is appended.
I have to select a document with a 'userId' field which is a unique key. If it exists, I'll append a new element in 'history' array in the existing document with 'sequence' set current 'auto_increment' and increase it by 1. If not, I'll insert new document with an element in 'history' array with 'sequence' 0 and initialize 'auto_increment' as 1. And I'd like to get the result of the update with the same query. It all has to run in ACID fashion. I'd just use SELECT FOR UPDATE if it is MySQL.
Here's the example of 'user_history' Collection
[
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "history": [
      {
        "sequence": 0,
        "foo": "bar"
      }
    ],
    "auto_increment": 1,
  }
]

Is it possible to achieve this only with the functions supported by MongoDB, such as findAndModify?
Or I couldn't help but to handle it with application logic, such as using optimistic locking and retry, or totally different solutions like distributed lock?

You can employ Aggregation update and upserts :
db.collection.updateOne(
    {user_id:1},
    [
        { $replaceRoot: { 
            newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ 
                { "user_id": 1, "history": [], "auto_increment": 0 }, 
                "$$ROOT"  
            ] } 
        } },
        { $set: { 
            history: { $concatArrays: [
                "$history", 
                [{
                    "sequence": {$add: ["$auto_increment", 1]},
                    "foo": "bar"
                }]
            ] }, 
            auto_increment: {$add: ["$auto_increment", 1]}
        } }
   ],{upsert: true})

{user_id:1} is your "select for update", and the [...] is the update pipeline.
The $replaceRoot stage implements "upsert" behaviour - if there is no matching document, $$ROOT will be empty, and the first element from $mergeObject will be used to replace the empty document. Otherwise $$ROOT will overwrite the first object (assuming all fields are there), i.e.  the document will be replaced with itself.
The $set stage appends history array and increments the auto_increment
As a side note name of auto_increment field might be a bit misleading, as there is nothing "auto" about it - you need to increment it manually. On the other side BSON guarantees order of items in an array, and depending on the intended use of the sequence you might be able to just rely on index of the item in the history array.

Thank you for letting me know about Aggregation Pipeline Updates! Then, how should I change this query to get the result of that query after performing that update in the same query in ACID way?

@SeanHwang Could you elaborate on "get the result" part? The updateOne returns metadata of the operation. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#returns I don't see how ACID could be applicable.
